# Download a file using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

What's the best way to allow a user to pull down an RDP file, but to do so using AJAX? In other words, I have a hyperlink and I need an RDP file to be downloaded by the user, but without a full page refresh.

I tried to make an AJAX call using the following example for RDP. It seems to work on Chrome and Firefox, but not on any version of IE.

```
   String content = <RDP Content Here>
   Response.Clear();
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=HelloWorld.rdp");
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   Response.ContentType = "Content-Type=application/x-rdp rdp;charset=ISO-8859-1";
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
   Response.Write(content);
   Response.End();
```

Comment: I just finished debugging a project that attempted to do what you were thinking here. An asynch response with an attachment Content-Disposition will not make any sense to a browser. Use Dustin E's solution below--it's the best practice in this case. If you'd like to keep the method inside your page's code beside, I'd recommend opening the link in a new window with a querystring parameter that causes Page_Load execution to call a function with the code from the OP above and exit.

Answer (score 3):

I'd create another page and put that code there. Then have that page open up in a new window when the link is clicked. Make you clear out any of the boiler plate code that VS automatically generates when you create a new file. That'll get you your data without a page refresh. I've done this with Excel pages and images and it's worked like a champ.